# Cannot get data from an Entry widget, and cannot concatenate it into a string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple program that runs the console command for automated delayed shutdown on Windows: "shutdown -s -t num", where num is the delay in seconds before the automated shutdown occurs. By hardcoding a predefined number there in the Python command os.system("cmd /c shutdown -s -t 1234") it works just fine. Then I created a Tkinter window with an entry widget, and a button to confirm. However, when trying to get data from the entry widget, something strange keeps happening.

Regardless of what is actually stored there, I always get "<bound method StringVar.get of <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x03DCE160>>". I tried to solve this by passing the data in the StringVar to a regular variable, but that just led to where I am now. When I try to add the string via a variable to the command, I get "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "method") to str". My minimum code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
class Shutdown_Timer(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.geometry("200x27")
        self.grid()

        self.time = StringVar()
        self.time.set("0")

        self.time_get = "0"

        self.Input = Entry(self)
        self.Input.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.submit = Button(self, text = "Start Timer", command = self.submit_time)
        self.submit.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

    def submit_time(self):
        self.time.set(self.Input.get)
        self.time_get = self.time.get
#Gives first error about bound method
        print(self.time_get)
#Gives second error (TypeError)
        print("cmd /c shutdown -s -t " + self.time_get)
       #os.system("cmd /c shutdown -s -t " + self.time_get)

frame01 = Shutdown_Timer()
frame01.mainloop
```

Changing it to

```
def submit_time(self):
        self.time_get = self.Input.get
        print(self.time_get)
        print("cmd /c shutdown -s -t " + self.time_get)
```

to pull the Entry directly into the normal variable instead gives "<bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.Entry object .!shutdown_timer.!entry>>" and then the same error about not concatenating a method and a string.

Comment: `self.Input.get` (for example) doesn't do anything - you're just mentioning the name of a method, not actually calling it.  That would be written `self.Input.get()`.

Comment: @ jasonharper Oh my, how careless of me. I apologize. Changing it to "self.time.set(self.Input.get())" throws the same errors. Cutting out the StringVar middle man like in the second example, however, actually works. Thank you very much!